# Japanese reports

Tags: grammar, written-language

I have a question about Japanese reports. I am studying at a university in Japan. And when I came here, I found out that Japanese people use ～だ instead ～です, ～たinstead ～ます and so on. And it seems rude to me. I'm afraid that I could misunderstand something and do it incorrectly. Are there any words I should avoid in the reports? How to use grammatical forms in reports? Which words to use and which not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, plain form is a standard for writing reports. In fact, 新完全マスター文法N3 has a chapter on this topic, on page 142. Here is what it says:

> In order to ensure a unified tone, casual and formal language are not used together. You should also adhere to a single register, whether using 丁寧体 (です and ます) or 普通体 (だ or である) verb forms.
>
> Formal language used in reports and articles should use the 普通体 (だ or である) forms. In addition, for continuity, the て form can also be replaced as follows:
>
> - 文法の小説を**読み**、例文を見た後で練習問題を**し**、答えを確認する
>
> In formal language, colloquially abbreviated forms (like みなきゃ) and omission of particles are not acceptable.

From there, the book gives a small table that compares the differences between expressions in formal language vs daily language:

> "formal" vs "daily language"
>
> - 非常に・大変　vs　すごく
> - 多く・大勢　vs　いっぱい
> - 少し　vs　ちょっと
> - やはり　vs　やっぱり
> - さまざまな・いろいろな　vs　いろんな
> - 述べる・話す・言う　vs　しゃべる
> - 行う　vs　やる
> - しかし・だが　vs　でも・だけど
> - なぜ　vs　なんで
> - ～など　vs　なんか
> - ～と・～という・～そうだ　vs　～って
> - ～ようだ・～らしい　vs　～みたいだ

Still, at the end of the day, to get a detailed conclusive answer, you have to consider the standards of writing in your field of study. You can probably find books and style guides on that topic.